Error RuntimeError: CUDA error: operation not supported when tried to locate something into CUDA
Here is my code:
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, QuantoConfig
import torch
device = "cuda:0"
model_id = "bigscience/bloom-560m"
quantization_config = QuantoConfig(weights="int8")

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float32,  device_map=device)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)

text = "Hello my name is"
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=20)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True))

When I run, I obtain the next error:

RuntimeError: CUDA error: operation not supported CUDA kernel errors
might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the
stacktrace below might be incorrect. For debugging consider passing
CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1. Compile with TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA to enable
device-side assertions.

However, when I check if CUDA is available I obtain:
print('-------------------------------')
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print(torch.cuda.device_count())
print(torch.cuda.current_device())
print(torch.cuda.device(0))
print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
print('Memory Usage:')
print('Allocated:', round(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0)/1024**3,1), 'GB')
print('Cached:   ', round(torch.cuda.memory_reserved(0)/1024**3,1), 'GB')


True 1 0 <torch.cuda.device object at 0x7f8bf6d4a9b0> GRID T4-16Q
Memory Usage: Allocated: 0.0 GB Cached: 0.0 GB

I run this code on Colab, and I do not have any issues. I also run the code on another machine with another GPU, and it runs as expected.
The configuration of the machine where I need to run it fails.

And the libraries:
accelerate 0.31.0 aiohttp 3.9.5 aiosignal 1.3.1 async-timeout 4.0.3 attrs 23.2.0 certifi 2024.6.2 charset-normalizer 3.3.2 datasets 2.20.0 dill 0.3.8 filelock 3.15.1 frozenlist 1.4.1 fsspec 2024.5.0 huggingface-hub 0.23.4 idna 3.7 Jinja2 3.1.4 MarkupSafe 2.1.5 mpmath
1.3.0 multidict 6.0.5 multiprocess 0.70.16 networkx 3.3 ninja 1.11.1.1 numpy 2.0.0 nvidia-cublas-cu12 12.1.3.1 nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12
12.1.105 nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12 12.1.105 nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12 12.1.105 nvidia-cudnn-cu12 8.9.2.26 nvidia-cufft-cu12 11.0.2.54 nvidia-curand-cu12 10.3.2.106 nvidia-cusolver-cu12 11.4.5.107 nvidia-cusparse-cu12 12.1.0.106 nvidia-nccl-cu12 2.20.5 nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12 12.5.40 nvidia-nvtx-cu12 12.1.105 packaging 24.1 pandas 2.2.2 pip 24.0 psutil 5.9.8 pyarrow 16.1.0 pyarrow-hotfix 0.6 python-dateutil 2.9.0.post0 pytz 2024.1 PyYAML 6.0.1 quanto 0.2.0 regex 2024.5.15 requests 2.32.3 safetensors 0.4.3 setuptools 65.5.0 six 1.16.0 sympy 1.12.1 tokenizers 0.19.1 torch 2.3.1 tqdm 4.66.4 transformers 4.42.0.dev0 triton 2.3.1 typing_extensions 4.12.2 tzdata
2024.1 urllib3 2.2.2 xxhash 3.4.1 yarl 1.9.4

I do not know if this affect you, but the machine is a virtual machine with wmware under a vgpu. Also, I tried to run a simple nn, just for check if the problem was with the transformers library, but I obtained the same error when I tried to locate info on the GPU.
 import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    dev = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
    t1 = torch.randn(1,2)
    t2 = torch.randn(1,2).to(dev)
    print(t1)  # tensor([[-0.2678,  1.9252]])
    print(t2)  # tensor([[ 0.5117, -3.6247]], device='cuda:0')
    t1.to(dev)
    print(t1)  # tensor([[-0.2678,  1.9252]])
    print(t1.is_cuda) # False
    t1 = t1.to(dev)
    print(t1)  # tensor([[-0.2678,  1.9252]], device='cuda:0')
    print(t1.is_cuda) # True

    class M(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):        
            super().__init__()        
            self.l1 = nn.Linear(1,2)

        def forward(self, x):                      
            x = self.l1(x)
            return x
    model = M()   # not on cuda
    model.to(dev) # is on cuda (all parameters)
    print(next(model.parameters()).is_cuda) # True


Traceback (most recent call last): File
“/home/admin/llm/ModelsService/test.py”, line 14, in t2 =
torch.randn(1,2).to(dev) RuntimeError: CUDA error: operation not
supported CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some
other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect. For
debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1. Compile with
TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA to enable device-side assertions.

by the way here info about my cuda

(test310) admin@appdev-llm-lnx1:~/llm/ModelsService$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA
Corporation Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019 Cuda compilation
tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

regards

Nobody wants to read e.g. your nvidia-smi output or library list because you formatted them in block quotes which got rid of a lot of useful whitespace. Please edit your question and use code blocks for such formatted output or files. See Help: Formatting (I recommend using triple ` on their own lines)

updated adding an image for nvidia-smi information

That is not what I was saying. Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

ok i will responds myself, if someone has a similar eror, just create the next environment variables:

export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

after that pytorch start working correctly
